# Android - Adobe creative SDK -Aviary v4.48 crash due to Proguard configuration

Tags: android, proguard, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I have googled it, also search in the Adobe documents and couldn't find the right Proguard configuration for Aviary v4.4.8.

Adobe change the Classes and Packages and the old Proguard from the Aviary website is not working. The app crash when building with Proguard.

Does anyone manage to fix it or can give me the right configuration? I have also sent three emails to Adobe without any comment from their side.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found some proguard rules that work?

Comment: Not yet :( I'm still trying to do it. For now I don't use proguard as Aviary is crucial for me

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/issues/25) - I managed to find a work around

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No proguard setting is required.

I updated to Creative SDK 4.4.8 from old Aviary SDK and had the same issue.  I solved this by removing all the proguard setting for Aviary (ex. `keep interface com.aviary.android.feather.** {*;}`)

Answer (score 1):

Use proguard and add this Line in it

```
-dontwarn com.adobe.**
```

It worked for me.I even signed and released it to my Beta channel in play store.Then I downloaded it from there and tested it and it's working fine till now.I am just using the Image Editor only.Let me know if it works.

Comment: I'll check it and or you know :)